# How to get the k smallest elements?

Tags: r

Assume I have the vector `c(3,7,1,9,7,6,4)` and I need to get its three least elements `c(3,1,4)`. How can I do it with R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
sort( c(3,7,1,9,7,6,4) )[1:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
sort(x = c(3,7,1,9,7,6,4), partial = 3)[1:3]
```

Which performs a [partial sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting).